# Android slide animation for linearlayout

Tags: android, animation, android-linearlayout, slide

One activity of my Android-app uses a linearlayout with a couple of textviews and one imageview. the textviews and the imageview get the data from a sqlite-database.
i also have two buttons (prev, next) to navigate back and forth through the database. works fine.

Now i want to add animation to my app: when i push the next-button the linearlayout (with the textviews and the image) should slide to the left and a linearlayout containing data from the next row should slide in from the right. the other way round for the prev-button.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: is the linearlayout  containing data another activity ? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using the translate tween animation.

Place the linearlayout holding the textviews, imageview and buttons in a parent Linear/Relative layout:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/parent_layout">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/container_layout">
        <Textview />

        <ImageView />

        <Buttons />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Define two translate tween animations in res/anim folder, one for previous and the other for next

```
 `previous.xml` -

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0">
</translate>

`next.xml` -

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromXDelta="100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0">
</translate>
```

Initialize the animations and get a reference of the "container" layout in the onCreate() method of the activity:

```
Animation previousAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainMenuActivity.this, R.anim.previous);
Animation nextAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainMenuActivity.this, R.anim.next);
LinearLayout containerLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container_layout);
```

When next and prev are clicked, navigate through the db, update the textviews,imageviews etc and fire the animations

```
previousButtonOnClick {
    //navigate db and update views 
    containerLayout.startAnimation(previousAnim);
}

nextButtonOnClick {
    //navigate db and update views 
    containerLayout.startAnimation(nextAnim);
}
```

Comment: 2nd part: I tried it: If I click on the prev/next button the current linearlayout is cleared immediately instead of sliding out. New values slide in as intended.

Comment: Then start the animation, check if slides out before "clearing"